# CSS ajax search box styling

Tags: css, ajax, search

I believe the styling of the ajax search results on my website (http://www.imbued.co.uk/) that drop down have an indent due to them popping as a none-styled list. How do I remove this indent?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: The search menu in the top bar @HK1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `livesearch.css` on please replace this `#livesearch_search_results` `css` with this one

```
#livesearch_search_results {
    background-color: #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    left: -100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-left: 0;

}
```

Comment: Cheers bud. I didn't realise padding isn't set to 0 as default

Comment: It should be if you use some kind of CSS reset.

Comment: Almost done! The little problem I see is that a black line is left when not showing anything. It is not completely hidden... ahh, I solved it by commenting out `border-bottom: 1px solid ghostwhite;`